# How can I open camera from lockscreen on jailbroken device?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos, tweak, springboard

How can I open camera from lockscreen?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] launchApplicationWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.camera" suspended:NO];
```

it doesn't work, because device is locked.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13 it works:

```
if (%c(SBLockScreenManager)) {
  SBLockScreenManager *manager = (SBLockScreenManager *)[%c(SBLockScreenManager) sharedInstance];
  if (manager != nil) {
    CSCoverSheetViewController *lock = [manager coverSheetViewController];
    if (lock != nil) {
      [lock activatePage:2 animated:NO withCompletion:nil];
    }
  }
}
```